# Find strings in txt file and move them in another txt

Tags: vbscript, text-files

Hi i need to make a script in vbs that do this:

- Find 3 strings and move them in another txt file.

So this is for example the input txt:

```
*************************************
NAME: NOTHING
FUNCTION: NOT IMPORTANT
DATA_START: 20/05/2013
DATA_STOP: 22/05/2013
*************************************
FUNCTION: NOT IMPORTANT
TIME_STOP: 21.00.00.00
*************************************
DATA_NUMBER: 0000000054
*************************************
```

Well this is the file.. Now, i have to "take" these strings:

DATA_START: 20/05/2013
DATA_STOP: 22/05/2013
TIME_STOP: 21.00.00.00
DATA_NUMBER: 0000000054

and move them in another txt writing:

```
20/05/2013 22/05/2013 21.00.00.00 0000000054
```

This is what i want..

I can't find the error

Comment: the problem is that i can extract what i what using a `do While Not OggTextStream.AtEndOfStream ... loop`. But when i write `OggTextStream1.Writeline` (inside the loop) the result is `20/05/2013 22/05/2013 21.00.00.00 0000000054` for 10 times..why?

Comment: I posted code that works, although I'd like to point out that no one could tell you what is wrong with your code unless you post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here try this:

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objInputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objInputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\input.txt", ForReading, False)
Dim objOutputTS 'Text Stream Object
Set objOutputTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\output.txt", ForWriting, True)

Do Until objInputTS.AtEndOfStream
    Dim strLine
    strLine = objInputTS.ReadLine()
    If (Left(strLine, 11) = "DATA_START:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 13))
    If (Left(strLine, 10) = "DATA_STOP:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 12))
    If (Left(strLine, 10) = "TIME_STOP:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 12))  
    If (Left(strLine, 12) = "DATA_NUMBER:") Then objOutputTS.WriteLine(Mid(strLine, 14))    
Loop

objOutputTS.Close()
objInputTS.Close()
```

Comment: now i try your code..but take a look at mine if you can please

Comment: your it goes. But, is it possible write the output in a single line?

Comment: Sure, you would just use objOutputTS.Write() instead of objOutputTS.WriteLine(), or you could build the string ahead of time and then use only one call to objOutputTS.WriteLine().